# Fileinput not working in my project

Tags: javascript, file-io, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a set up form to use fileinput with the code below.
HTML the part where I included the files

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
        <link  href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <!--- JQuery --->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!--- JQuery UI--->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css"/>

        <!--- Bootstrap.js--->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!--- File Input --->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/plugins/fileinput/css/fileinput.min.css"/>

    </head>

    <body>

        <!--- File Input JS--->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/fileinput/js/plugins/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/fileinput/js/plugins/sortable.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/fileinput/js/plugins/purify.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/fileinput/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/fileinput/js/jquery-fileinput/dist/jquery.fileinput.min.js"></script>


<!-- avatar markup--> 
<div id="kv-avatar-errors-1" class="center-block" style="width:800px;display:none;"></div>
<div class="kv-avatar center-block" style="width:200px;">
<input type="file" id="productImage" name="productImage" class="file-loading" style="width:auto;"/>
</div>
</div>

    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#productImage').fileinput({
       overwriteInitial: true,
       maxFileSize: 1500,
       showClose: false,
       showCaption: false,
       browseOnZoneClick: true,
       removeLabel: '',
       browseIcon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>',
       removeIcon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>',
       removeTitle: 'Cancel or reset changes',
       elErrorContainer: '#kv-avatar-errors-1',
       msgErrorClass: 'alert alert-block alert-danger',
       defaultPreviewContent: '<img src="assets/images/sample.png" alt="Your 
Avatar" style="width:160px">',
       layoutTemplates: {
        main2: '{preview} {remove} {browse}'
       },
       allowedFileExtensions: [
        "jpg", 
        "png", 
        "gif"
       ]

     }); 
    });
```

My prblem is this just puts a reload icon on my page without the actual fileinput features I have specified in my code.
Firefox gives me this error: **TypeError: $(...).fileinput is not a function[Learn More]** I don't understand why that is because am expecting bootstrap fileinput to have setup that function already.

Please can someone help me? Three days now I have been going through my code I don't know where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I do not use jQuery, but in your case it seems you are missing a jQuery plugin. Have a look at [jQuery Plugins](https://plugins.jquery.com/fileinput/).

Also, the same site offers you a nice [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hleinone/UF4nr/) where you can see it in action.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type=file][name=foo]").fileinput();
    $("input[type=file][name=bar]").fileinput("<button>Search...</button>");
    $("input[type=file][name=baz]").fileinput($("#replacement").remove());
});
```

Comment: My jquery plugin is intact and working. Firefox debugger says TypeError: $(...).fileinput is not a function[Learn More]

Comment: It tells you the plugin is not loaded. Check the links I provided on how to load it to jQuery

Comment: Which plugin? jquery or the fileinput plugin?

Comment: Message says jQuery does not contain that method, which in turn means  did not load the fileinput plugin for whatever reason. You should provide your HTML code as well.

Comment: The html file is long can I send it to you via mail? If that is ok.

Comment: Please do not. You could edit your original question, and add the beginning of the HTML file, where you include the jQuery, or any other scripts. No need for the whole file.

Comment: When I view the source code of the page and click on the loaded libraries, everything checked out fine.

Comment: I have edited the code to add the HTML. Even though am still in the woods, I appreciate your help. Thank you in advance

Comment: have you tried moving fileinput.min.js inside <head> after other declarations?